# Visual studio C# unit test System.Net.Http.Formatting assembly not loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to write tests for my Web API project. But keep running into a runtime exception when executing anything on my Web API controllers.
[image]

My test project builds fine. But when running, Visual studio complains about System.Net.HTTP.Formatting.dll that can't be loaded.
I checked the version between my main project and my test project and all DLL versions are equal.

full error:

> Message: Test method Tests.TagsTests.HappyFlowTests threw exception: 
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Kan bestand of assembly
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.6.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 of een van de afhankelijkheden hiervan
>   niet laden. De manifestdefinitie van de gevonden assembly komt niet
>   overeen met de assembly-verwijzing. (Uitzondering van HRESULT:
>   0x80131040) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Kan bestand of assembly
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 of een van de afhankelijkheden hiervan
>   niet laden. De manifestdefinitie van de gevonden assembly komt niet
>   overeen met de assembly-verwijzing. (Uitzondering van HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

Losely translated

> Message: Test method Tests.TagsTests.HappyFlowTests threw exception: 
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Can't load file or assembly
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.6.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 or one of it's dependencies.
>   The found manifest doesn't match the referenced assembly. (exception HRESULT:
>   0x80131040) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Can't load file or assembly
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 or one of it's dependencies.The found manifest doesn't match the referenced assembly. (exception HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

I've tried to clean and rebuild the solution in multiple different ways. But there seems to be something wrong somewhere that it keeps having issues with the DLL.

```
My tests packages.config
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
    </packages>
```

My main project's packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.4.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've suffered this bizzare error today. I found for some reason if I am using a HttpClient extension method. In my case `httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync`. As soon as I replaced my extension method with the more long winded.

`httpClient.PostAsync("/path/", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")`.

The problem went away, despite the extension method seeming to live under the same namespace / assembly as 'StringContent'.

I may try to reproduce this later and maybe raise it as a potential SDK bug, but at least for myself I have a workaround.